# Firebase and ObjC: use of undeclared identifier 'user'

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

My project uses both swift 3 and objective C so my appDelegate is in Swift.

I'm importing Firebase.h into the objective C code and I can access and add data to Firebase.   But when I try to use the child:user.uid to apply it to the logged in user I get the undeclared error on the user object:

```
[[[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"user"] child:user.uid] setValue:@{@"fname":@"bob"}];
```

[image: Image of error message]

Comment: Post the complete method containing this line of code. The error is clear though. There is no variable named `user` in the scope used by this line of code.

Comment: i know but the documentation from Firebase doesnt show that they have declared a user anywhere either.  I dont know what to set that variable with and their documenation doesnt show it.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data

Answer (score 0):

Finally found where/how to declare the user variable.

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
```